# PHP: locale-dependent float to string cast

Tags: php, string, casting, locale

I'm sitting on a machine with en_US locale and this piece of PHP code

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE.utf8');
var_dump((string)1.234);
```

returns

```
string(5) "1.234"
```

whereas on my colleague's machine which has a German locale, it returns

```
string(5) "1,234"
```

Why the heck does PHP use the locale when typecasting floats to strings? How can I disable it? I'd like to have this function return string(5) "1.234" on all machines, regardless of any locale settings.

Secondly and less important: Why does PHP ignore the setlocale on my machine?

Comment: it doesn't ignore the setlocale, you have to have the locale installed, (doesn't work in windows) check the return value of setlocale if its FALSE then you don't have the locale.

Comment: @DevZer0.. a right, I guess it just isn't installed on my machine...

Comment: http://php.net/setlocale has a return value, you do not check for it in your questions code so we can not tell you if the setting of the locale was successful or just ignored.

Answer (score 7):

> Why the heck does PHP use the locale when typecasting floats to strings?

That's its behaviour

> How can I disable it?

You can't (as far as I know).

You may set locale to `en_US` if you have **locale** installed.

> I'd like to have this function return string(5) "1.234" on all machines, regardless of any locale settings.

You have several options:

```php
$num = 1.234; 


/* 1 - number format                            */

$str = number_format( $num, 3, '.', '' );
       
/*     you get exacly the number of digits      *
 *     passed as 2nd parameter.  Value  is      *
 *     properly rounded.                        */



/* 2 - sprintf                                  */

$str = sprintf( '%.3F', $num );

/*     you get exacly the number of digits      *
 *     specified bewtween `.` and `F`.          *
 *     Value is properly rounded.               */



/* 3 - json encode                              *
 *     optionally setting serialize_precision   */

ini_set( 'serialize_precision', 3 );
$str = json_encode( (float) $num );

/*     you get  -AT MOST-  the  number  of      *
 *     digits   as   per  language  option      *
 *     `serialize_precision`                    *
 *     If the number  can  be  represented      *
 *     with less digits  without  loss  of      *
 *     precision then trailing zeroes  are      *
 *     trimmed.                                 *
 *     If  `serialize_precision`  is  `-1`      *
 *     then all the available decimals are      *
 *     written.                                 *
 *     Note that altering the language opt      *
 *     affect all foat serialization funcs      *
 *     so you may want to set it  back  to      *
 *     its   previous  value   after   the      *
 *     conversion.                             *
 *     Value is  properly  rounded  unless       *
 *     `serialize_precision` is set to -1.      */
```

> Secondly and less important: Why does PHP ignore the setlocale on my machine?

As [DevZer0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990684/devzer0) commented you may not have locale installed.

Comment: Instead of `en_US` you can set the locale to `C` with `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C')`. This should work on every system to get the language independet “default” behavior.